# Potential Western Union Scam - Account Registration

Tags: email, account-security, email-spoofing, scam

In recent weeks I have seen a handful of senior employees in my organization receive a confirmation email from Wester Union for a new account creation. The issue is that none of these users have created a WU account.

I have verified all links in the email and it is NOT a phishing campaign. These are legitimate emails from WU. But for some reason someone out there is registering WU accounts with my employee's business email addresses.

What I do not understand is why. Initial thoughts would be that this is an impersonation scam. However, the user's name in WU does not match the actual user's name (which the attacker clearly has in the email address schema)

What motivation would someone have for this type of 'attack'?

Comment: Interesting case, I can't imagine the root cause either. One thing I've thought about is maybe a typo from the applicant, but if the name doesn't match - that's most strange. If I turn paranoid mode on, I can think of it being a preparation stage, followed later by state 2 "Oh, I've sent 1000 dollars and need to cancel, but I accidentally registered your email, please go to the website hxxps://western-union.legit.not.scam/profile and untie your account"...    Next question, are you 100% sure it's from WU? Can you share email headres here, stripped from your company's emails/domains/addresses?

Comment: Yeah, 100% sure it is WU. I've been reading up on this and the only thing that really makes sense is that it is a poorly executed impersonation attack.